# Battery Indicator not working

Tags: release-juno, wingpanel, battery

I am having problems with the battery indicator. If i have no moes plugged i, it does not even appear on the top bar. When i connect a mouse, it appears, but the icon never changes, and the percentage is stuck on 0.

[image]
[image]

It charges fine, but not being able to see how much power is left is really a hindrance.

I am on a surface pro 5.

Comment: Please provide the output of `upower -i upower -e | grep 'BAT'`

Comment: That command doesn't seem to do anything, i found another one which gives me this: https://i.imgur.com/foZ0uTA.png

Thanks for trying to help.

Comment: Ok, my command was checking for Battery (whichs are called BATx) and your command was just checking BAT0. So, but we can see is, that the system is not detecting any battery. Have you installed the correct Battery or is it a aftermarket battery from a different manufacturer?

Answer (score 1):

A kind person pointed me towards a special kernel for the Surface models, and after installing it, everything works as it should.

https://github.com/jakeday/linux-surface